# error on Django drf ModelSerializer update method

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have a very strange error, this is my serializer class

```
class user_ser(ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = '__all__'
        depth = 1
```

whenever I send an API request to update user data, i got default values for is_staff and is_superuser

in the image below I send only email and password

example :
[image]

look what I got :(

this is the validated_data for the update method is :
[image]

I did not add is_staff or anything else to the request body, so why is that happening.

Comment: That's the default fields for the default user model. There's default boolean values for is_staff (user can access admin page) and is_superuser.

Comment: If you wish to suppress this fields from appearing on the response of the serializer, declare explicitly the fields you want.

Comment: I already make the default values for those is true in my models file

Comment: You're using the PUT method, usually it doesn't allow partial updates (which would use PATCH). Probably DRF is trying to populate these fields and evaluating them as False. Which is causing the changes. Try using patch instead (partial_update if you're using a model viewset). If you must use PUT anyway, pass a flag partial=True in the serializer declaration in your views.py (serializer = YourSerializerClass(data=request.data, partial=True))

Comment: @pzvkn thank you very much you solve my problem.

Answer (score 0):

That's normal behavior; `is_staff` and `is_superuser` are default fields in Django used for authorization of admin users. You can view them as columns in the DB.

The real problem comes from using `fields = '__all__'` in the Meta class.
This is an anti-pattern since you can expose fields you didn't intend to expose. You should explicitly display fields that you intend to use.

> Explicit is better than implicit.